# Change app theme programmatically Android Studio using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme

I'm making an Android application using Kotlin. It contains App Theme color list so the user can select one color from it, and then I save this color in Shared Preferences.

I've done with all Shared Preferences and XML values stuff, and I've succeeded to change the theme smoothly in the settings activity, and when I reopen the application I find the saved color successfully in settings activity.

The problem is: the changes happens on settings activity only, not in the whole app, and if I want to affect all activities I should use `setTheme()` in each activity's `onCreat()`.
I don't want to do that since my application has many activities.

Is there better approach to achieve that.

I tried to call `setTheme()` method on `Application` class, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you don't want to do it in every Activity, but with activities there is no other approach than setting theme in each one of them.

I would suggest you to create abstract parent e.g. `BaseActivity` and call `setTheme()` here inside `onCreate()`. Then you will update your activities just to extend the `BaseActivity` and make sure you are calling `super.onCreate()`.

It's faster then pasting the code in every activity individually and it's nicer and more scalable solution.